# Filling two textbox with the same functions in php

Tags: php, javascript

I need to fill the code and initials of a employment with the same javascript functions.
The java script function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Expedisi(t) {
        var y = document.getElementById("code");
        y.value = t.value;
    }
</script>


<tr>
   <td width="200px" align="right"><label for=""><font color="0099FF"size="3px">Code</font><span></span></label></td>
   <td align="left"><input type="text" id="code"  name="code" value=" <?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $get['loan'] : ""; ?>" class="form-input-code" readonly />
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="200px" align="right"><label for=""><font color="0099FF" size="3px">Employee Name </font><span></span></label>
    </td>
    <td align="left"><select data-placeholder="Employee Name" style="width:332px;" id="cmbemployee" name="cmbemployee" class="chzn-select-deselect" onchange="Expedisi(this)""/>
        <option value="<?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $gete['accode'] : ""; ?>"><?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $gete['name'] : ""; ?></option>
        <?php
        $mown = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accmast WHERE grpcode='044'") or die(mysql_error());
        while($trow = mysql_fetch_array($mown))
        {
          echo "<option value=$trow[accode]>$trow[name]</option>";
        }
        ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Where is initials..??

Comment: Initials is just another textbox with id="init" & name="init1"

Comment: `var y=document.getElementById("code"), z=document.getElementById("init");
    y.value = t.value;
    z.value = t.value;`

Comment: Please read some tutorials before, then ask proper question. Starting the question with 'I need' is not a proper question, sorry.

Comment: well mr wiggler i am new to stackoverflow so plz don't mind

Answer (score 0):

you can no get value of select element in js!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Expedisi(t) {
        var y = document.getElementById("code");
        y.value = t.options[t.selectedIndex].innerHTML
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place single quotes (`''`)around the value.

```
while($trow = mysql_fetch_array($mown))
{
  echo "<option value='{$trow[accode]}'>{$trow[name]}</option>";
}
```